Unknown 80s movie with closet-portal & goat-legged man
I am trying to figure out this movie I watched when I was a kid and I'm pretty sure it is from the 80s, kind of spooked me. All I can remember is they go the closet and open the hangers of clothes and through the closet is a "portal" into another dimension. There was an ugly half man with goat legs...lol sorry to be brief but this is all I remember and was "scarred" by. :-) However I feel it should be distinctive enough... Hopefully! :)
Thanks!
DMD
PS This was not a cartoon.
Any answers appreciated and sorry for the delayed edit. :)

Thanks for the extra info (this not being a cartoon). Adjusted my answer accordingly.

Could be The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe where 4 kids enter a wardrobe and wind up in the magical land of Narnia; one of them (Lucy) first meets a faun (half man, half goat) called Tumnus. Judging by the year, you probably mean the live-action 1988 UK version.
Here's Lucy meeting the faun from that version (around 0:40):




Interestingly it does seem like it could be the 1988 version of The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe. Although when I looked at the footage it did not seem to be familiar, however who knows how much my memory altered and let the concepts grow over the years. Thanks for the quick response! What an awesome site!!!!!

As I remember it was a movie not a TV series, was there maybe a 90s movie similar?

Doesn't seem to be one in the adaptations that are specified here. There's the 2005 movie, of course, but that's way off.

@IrateHateCore I remember seeing this back-to-back on BBC at Christmas several times, that would certainly make it feel like a movie as there's no ad breaks on the BBC.

if you didn't find the movie yet, i kinda feel like you are looking for "House (1986)" series...check out the clip too. Thank you :) https://www.youtube.com/v/kek5PKnhDNI

"This video is not available in your country". Message from youtube from within the US, my perceived dominant userbase for StackExchange.

I could use Google, if I were that interested. I'm questioning the usefulness of adding a link to a youtube most won't be able to view. That failed delivery is of more interest to me.

can you check the link again? i did update them :)

Can you include some more information about the match? Answers to 'identify this' questions should typically include the points of the film which match the given description.
